# Understanding comparison operators on columns

Tags: postgresql, union, operator

Consider this `dummy_data`:

| number |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

I want to **return all the rows from `dummy_data` where column `number` is below a certain value**.

Came up with this:

```sql
WITH
  dummy_data AS
  (
    (SELECT 1 AS number) UNION (SELECT 2) UNION (SELECT 3) UNION (SELECT 4) UNION (SELECT 5)
  )
  , some_selection AS
  (
    (SELECT 3 AS number) -- in my use case, this query might return nothing...
    UNION
    (SELECT 0 AS number) -- ...so I'm using the union to 0 to sort of coalesce.
  )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  dummy_data
  , some_selection
WHERE
  dummy_data.number < some_selection.number
;
```

Which returns:

| number | number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |

So this seems to work like I intended, but I don't understand enough what's going on to know if I can rely on this code.

**Can I be guaranteed that the comparison is always based on the *max* value of `some_selection.number`?** Or should I add an intermediate step to **explicitly extract `max(some_selection.number)`**?

i.e. is the comparison based on the whole column or just on a single semi-random cell?
i.e. I'm worried the comparison might at times be performed on `< 0` which would return very different results.

It's probably in the Postgres manual somewhere, but I could not find the relevant section.

Comment: A little side-note: you can simplify your "sample data" by using a `values (.),(.)` clause instead of the (in my opinion) cumbersome `select .. union ..`. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9f9cf1a3b95edbc541d553d752e146a3

Comment: note that your WHERE condition boils down to a join with a non-equality join condition `FROM dummy_data JOIN some_selection ON dummy_data.number < some_selection.number`

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is performed a [`CROSS JOIN`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cross-join/) and then filtered on the result of that `CJ`! What a `CROSS JOIN` does is combine every field in the first table with every field in the second and is not frequently very useful - but [not always](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cross-join/) unproductive!

Take the first small example:  (a PostgreSQL fiddle for all of the code in this answer is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6c1703700514b0540be41d4fe72c0106))

```
CREATE TABLE x (y INT, z TEXT); INSERT INTO x VALUES (1, 'h'), (2, 'i');
CREATE TABLE a (b INT, c TEXT); INSERT INTO a VALUES (8, 'r'), (9, 's');
```

Then:

```
SELECT x.y, x.z, a.b, a.c FROM x, a;
```

Result:

```
y   z   b   c
1   h   8   r
1   h   9   s
2   i   8   r
2   i   9   s
```

The systax below (called [ANSI](https://www.orafaq.com/node/2618) join - also, see the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))):

```
SELECT * FROM x CROSS JOIN a;
```

is perhaps better because you're being explicit about your requirements (see fiddle).

Things are perhaps easier to understand if you eliminate the extraneous SQL from your statement above. In this case, I specifically mean your use of the [`COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) (`CTE` - aka the `WITH` clause) - instead, I'd do the following:

- create the tables separately as follows:

  ```
   CREATE TABLE dat (d_num INT NOT NULL);
   INSERT INTO dat VALUES (1), (2), (3);
  ```
- and

  ```
  CREATE TABLE rand (r_num INT NOT NULL);
  INSERT INTO rand VALUES (-23), (5), (3), (1);
  ```

So, now perform the CROSS JOIN with **no filter**. Just a note - you should be using `ANSI` joins - see [this article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-for-beginners-joins) from the excellent oracle-base site.

```
SELECT 
  d.d_num AS dn, 
  r.r_num AS rn 
FROM dat d, rand r
ORDER BY dn, rn;
```

Which can be rewritten:

```
SELECT 
  d.d_num AS dn, r.r_num AS rn FROM dat d
CROSS JOIN rand r
ORDER BY dn, rn;
```

Result:

```
dn     rn
 1    -23
 1      1
 1      3      <<---- rn > dn
 1      5      <<---- rn > dn
 2    -23
 2      1
 2      3      <<---- rn > dn
 2      5      <<---- rn > dn
 3    -23
 3      1
 3      3
 3      5      <<---- rn > dn
 
12 rows
```

So, now we filter (keeping ANSI syntax):

```
SELECT 
  d.d_num AS dn, r.r_num AS rn 
FROM dat d
CROSS JOIN rand r
WHERE d.d_num < r.r_num
ORDER BY dn, rn;
```

Result:

```
dn  rn
 1   3
 1   5    -- <<--- note 5 = MAX(r_num)
 2   3
 2   5    -- <<--- note 5 = MAX(r_num)
 3   5    -- <<--- note 5 = MAX(r_num)

 5 rows
```

And we can see that these 5 rows correspond to the 5 rows from the original `CROSS JOIN`.

So, to answer your question:

> Can I be guaranteed that the comparison is always based on the max
> value of some_selection.number? Or should I add an intermediate step
> to explicitly extract max(some_selection.number)?

Your SQL will pick every number combination where **ANY** number in the first field is **less** than **ANY** number in the second field. This will pick any number that is less than the `MAX()` of field 2, but also any other combination where field 2 is greater than field 1.

If you want to just pick **ANY** number in the first table is less than the **MAX()** of the second table, you need to further refine your filter using a sub-`SELECT` as follows:

```
SELECT 
  d.d_num AS dn, r.r_num AS rn 
FROM dat d
CROSS JOIN rand r
WHERE d.d_num < r.r_num
AND r.r_num = (SELECT MAX(r_num) FROM rand)  <<--- New condition!
ORDER BY dn, rn;
```

Result:

```
dn  rn
 1   5
 2   5
 3   5
```

And we can see that this result corresponds to the 3 records where 5 is the rn above.

A few words of advice:

- make your initial SQL as simple as possible - using the `WITH` clause to generate data (IMHO) made your SQL more complex and didn't contribute to understanding.
- use table and column aliases to make your SQL more readable.
- when testing any of your solutions, always try to use weird outlier values (see -23 above) - I had 17 as well as 5, but the number of results of the `CJ` started to become too large - I just needed one value that was greater than all the values in the `dat` table.
- **EVERY** SQL statement **should** (I would say **MUST**) have an `ORDER BY` clause - leaving this out is one of the biggest factors leading to confusion with results and what record in table A corresponds to what record in table B. I believe that in this case, using `ORDER BY` helps comprehension!
- you used a variable called `NUMBER` in your example - you should never use [`SQL keywords`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words) as table or column names. This avoids confusion with error messages, aids with debugging and makes any query more portable - different systems escape keywords in different ways!
- always include your server (**and version**) in your questions - for this case, the SQL would have worked for any server, but answers can frequently depend on these factors.
- persist with the ANSI syntax (do a search for `sql ansi joins versus old style join`) - it seems strange at first, but is worth the effort!

p.s. bon courage avec ton anglais - qui n'est pas mauvais du tout d'ailleurs!

Comment: "EVERY SQL statement should (I would say MUST) have an ORDER BY clause" - I don't think it's a good advice, I would say never use ORDER BY if you don't really need it, otherwise database server will spend extra resources to sort data.

Comment: @NikitaSerbskiy - maybe within sub-SELECTs, but always for the final result (IMHO)!

Comment: Imaging that you use ORACLE, where would you prefer to sort the final result - on database server (where pay $20000 per core) or on application server (where CPU cores are relatively "free")? Especially when end user don't even need this result to be sorted :)

Comment: @NikitaSerbskiy - the point that I am making is that using `ORDER BY` makes **understanding** exactly what's going on (esp. for beginning SQL programmers) **much** easier - if you've records sorted in insertion order, resultsets can look like random garbage, whereas if they're sorted it's easy (or easier at least) to relate fields in table X with those in table Y and what exactly the `JOIN` (any kind of `JOIN`) results mean! I'm not fussed if sorting is done on the db or the app server - but they should be sorted, esp.  when learning!

Comment: ok, accepted ) just wanted to be sure the beginning SQL programmers will not start to put ORDER BY everywhere in their code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  dummy_data
  , some_selection
WHERE
  dummy_data.number < some_selection.number
;
```

it means database server should join each row from dummy_data to each row from some_selection where your condition is true. So first logically you get this table:

| dummy_data.number | some_selection.number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 |

Only two rows from this table match your condition.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I be guaranteed that the comparison is always based on the max
> value of some_selection.number?

Not as it's written in the question, as explained in other answers, but if you want to do just that, a join with the selection of values is not needed.

To simply test against the max of the list, you may write:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  dummy_data
WHERE
  dummy_data.number < (select max(number) from some_selection);
```

This comparison is valid because as an aggregate function, `max` returns a single row.